# Reading checkbox values using implode function

Tags: php, mysql

I have inserted this form with multiple checkbox items which collects some values, What i need to do is echo this values as a string separated by a comma, but i'm getting error in the implode function, it says Invalid arguments passed.

Can you please see the code?

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST);
    $checked = mysql_real_escape_string(implode(',', $_POST['checkbox'])); 
    echo $checked;
}
?>
```

HTML Form

```
<form action="checkbox.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="hostess_name">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="hostess_familyname_en">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="hostess_id">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="hostess_firstname_en">
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: can we have a look at the HTML form?

Comment: What does that print_r show? Could you put in the results of that.

Comment: can you tell me a better way to store the multiple checkboxes in an array then explode it?

Comment: Could you copy and paste the results of that array? Without seeing the actual data you are working with, it's difficult for me to say what could be happening.

Comment: use foreach loop to execute.

e.g. : $result = $_POST['checkbox'];
foreach($result as $i)
{

Comment: @GazetaAlmedicus Even though you accepted an answer, you should read the portion of my answer dealing with `mysql_real_escape_string` and the other `mysql_*` functions. I know that some tutorials still preach the use of `mysql_real_escape_string`, `mysql_connect`, etc. but these functions should *not* be used in any new code, and if you're a beginner to PHP, you shouldn't even touch these functions. Instead, prepared statements and PDO/MySQLi are at minimum the only libraries you should be using. Under no circumstances should you use `mysql_*` functions anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST);
    $checked = implode(',', $_POST['checkbox']); 
    echo $checked;
}
```

here's the exact stuff I put in my `test.php`

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    echo "<pre>";
    $checked = implode(',', $_POST['checkbox']);
    echo $checked;
}

?>
<form action="test.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="hostess_name">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="hostess_familyname_en">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="hostess_id">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="hostess_firstname_en">
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: sorry, the `array_values()` wasn't necessary

Comment: Huh, it still gives me this, it always gives me this... :@
Invalid arguments passed in implode function

Comment: @GazetaAlmedicus, well I've just tried it on my local server and it's working. Here's the output http://i47.tinypic.com/ea4ai1.png

Comment: Can you please insert the code you used here? Just to take a look at it.. i might have done something stupid.. maybe it has to do with my php version, i don't know

Comment: Hey, it worked like a charm, thanks so much :) it was all i needed :)
Thanks again!

Comment: I don't get what happened, but hey.. sure.. whatever makes you happy.

Answer (score 1):

Adnan's code is working for me as well. To the OP, could you post the results of the `print_r` statement so we can verify that something is being posted for the checkboxes? Your `isset` code checks that the form has been submitted, but I want to make sure something is being submitted for the checkboxes as well.

I have a few other comments on the OP's question as well, however, based on several things I notice. A) You use `echo "<pre>"` but you never use echo a closing tag with `echo "</pre>"`. Maybe you just left this code off, but that might garble your output down the line if you leave off closing tags.

B) Please don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) (see the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)). Instead, you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you. If you care to learn, [this is a good PDO tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

You'll find that using prepared statements not only makes your code more secure, but it's also significantly simpler to implement in code.

Answer (score 0):

use foreach loop to execute.

e.g. :

```
$result = $_POST['checkbox'];
foreach($result as $i)
{
//your code goes here
}
```

Comment: Hello Bikas, thanks for the reply, can you please be more specific with me? I find it difficult to understand, i'm new to this, so what am i supposed to put down the code section. in order to retrieve multiple checkbox values and store them in an array, in order to implode them..

Comment: the $result I specified itself an array. it contains all the values checked.

Comment: yes but what am i supposed to insert inside the part you say // your code goes here

Comment: whatever you like. if you want to insert into database. or you may echo it. your wish what you will do with the result.